Microsoft Graph EducationAssignment: How to define culture on publish
When an education assignment is published via the graph API by using this request:
POST /education/classes/{class-id}/assignments/{assignment-id}/publish    

The author of that assignment will get a new activity in her teams client in english:

If we are going to publish a similar assignment via the teams client, the activity will be in german:

Unfortunately we didn't find any property within the Graph API to set the desired culture of an assignment. Due to this fact, we looked into the calls, that are made by the Teams client and this doesn't use the Graph API. Instead it uses
POST https://assignments.onenote.com/api/v1.0/edu/classes/{class-id}/assignments/{assignment-id}/publish

And instead of providing an empty body like the Graph API, it sends a lot of information about the assignment itself:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://assignments.onenote.com/api/v1.0/edu/$metadata#classes('{class-id}')/assignments/$entity",
    "additionalClassIds": [],
    "classId": "{class-id}",
    "displayName": "Test via Teams",
    "closeDateTime": null,
    "dueDateTime": "2024-11-27T22:59:00Z",
    "originalDueDateTime": null,
    "latestExtendedDueDateTime": null,
    "assignDateTime": null,
    "assignedDateTime": null,
    "gradingSchemeHidePoints": null,
    "allowLateSubmissions": true,
    "resourcesFolderUrl": null,
    "feedbackResourcesFolderUrl": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2024-11-26T07:47:51.4728884Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-11-26T07:48:52.1413548Z",
    "allowStudentsToAddResourcesToSubmission": true,
    "status": "published",
    "statusreason": "none",
    "isCompleted": false,
    "anySubmittedState": false,
    "allTurnedIn": false,
    "channelId": null,
    "notificationChannelUrl": null,
    "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{...}",
    "addToCalendarType": "none",
    "disableAssignmentCardMessaging": false,
    "addedStudentAction": "none",
    "cultureName": "de",
    "enableLateSubmissionNotifications": false,
    "returnAllInProgress": false,
    "showReflectExitTicket": false,
    "reflectExitTicketState": "NotStarted",
    "classworkModuleId": null,
    "moduleUrl": null,
    "id": "7c285fe4-953e-48b0-9d82-2e6d10ae528d",
    "multiClassSettings": [],
    "instructions": {
        "content": "<div>Testaufgabe via Teams</div>",
        "contentType": "html"
    },
    "grading": null,
    "assignTo": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationAssignmentClassRecipient"
    },
    "resourcesFolder": null,
    "createdBy": {
        "application": null,
        "device": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "85a57f30-c528-4965-a70f-4339f94f071f",
            "displayName": null
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "application": null,
        "device": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "5e3ce6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-75ee78787346",
            "displayName": null
        }
    },
    "backfillSetting": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationNoBackfill"
    },
    "externalAssignment": null
}

The interesting property seems to be cultureName and I guess, that this will define the language to use to create the activity, emails, etc. Unfortunately this property can't be set via Graph API and there doesn't seem to be an official documentation for assignments.onenote.com available.
Does anyone have an idea, on how to configure the desired culture to be used for an education assignment publishment? The tenant and user are both already set to German culture, but this doesn't have any effect.
